# Reading a Google Protocol buffer .pb file using protoc

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I have compiled Google Protobuf from the source and generated the `protoc` binary. Now, given a `.pb` file, i.e., `tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb` how am I gonna be able to read its content **without** using the `Tensorflow` library ?

Currently, I can write a sample reader to dump the event of my `.pb` file later be read by `tensorboard`as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

INCEPTION_LOG_DIR = '/tmp/inception_v3_log'

if not os.path.exists(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = './model/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    #writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR, graph_def)
    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR, graph_def)                                                
    writer.close()
```

However, I don't quite get the reason why I compiled `protoc` for?  Can't it be used as a standalone reader? Or, the mentioned inception.pb file is already using Protocol buffer in the backend of the Tensorflow without the need of using `protoc`?

commands like these do generate error:

```
protoc --python_out=. tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb
protoc --cpp_out=. tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb
```

As I checked, `.pb` files are semi-readable, however, I could not find a solid answer to my question anywhere to directly parse this file's content. Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: `protoc` (and a range of 3rd-party tools) can be used to emit code in a *wide range* of languages / frameworks; most protobuf usage does not relate to tensorflow *in any way*; the exact APIs involved depends on the language / framework you are interested in. So: what language / framework would you like to use? You mention "commands like these do generate error:" - but: that command expects a `.proto` *schema*, not a data file. `protoc` *can* interpret data files, but that isn't the usual usage. Do you have a schema file somewhere?

Comment: to be specific: there are 2 ways of using `protoc` with data files - one involves a `.proto` and a data file, one involves just data files but gives less clear results; neither is probably what you want...

Comment: Thanks, @MarcGravell. I thought I could use `protoc` as as viewer of `.pb` as well. I don't have the `.proto` schema of my `.pb` file. So you said .pb is a data file and protoc can interpret this? say I would like to use in a `cpp` or `python` framework.

Comment: it *sounds* like it is a data file; note that something like the protoc raw decode functionality of protoc is also available at https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode - there is a command line option on protoc - something like "decode_raw" - try /? And --help etc

Comment: tested that already, `--decode_raw` says: `When using --decode_raw, no input files should be given.`

Comment: you might need to "pipe" the input (stdin) - or just try my website :)

Comment: yes. Thanks ! piping the stdin with --decode_raw generates I guess that `.proto` structure. It has a tree-like structure. please write an answer so I accept it.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I was wondering if you could suggest me a way to decode the file using .proto, this doesn't work: `protoc --decode MSG --proto-path=/PATH/TO/PROTOs file.proto < frozen_PBfile.pb` Thanks in advance!

Comment: define "this doesn't work" - what happens?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `protoc` can also be used to decode .pb files.

```
protoc --decode_raw < my_input.pb
```

will output the raw structure of the file.  This is not very useful, because (contrary to, e.g., XML or JSON) protobuf files do not contain as much structural information (element names), but that is "outsourced" into the .proto files.

If you have the correct .proto files, in this case from the tensorflow repository, you can use `-I path_to_tensorflow_checkout` and specify the correct message type name.  Note that in the tensorflow .proto files, all types are in the tensorflow package, so you have to prefix the type name.  Working example:

```
protoc --decode tensorflow.SavedModel tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto < path_to_saved_model.pb
```

(In this case, I ran the command from the tensorflow repository directory, omitting the `-I` / `--proto_path`.)

Depending on your [model file format (SavedModel or GraphDef)](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files), you might need to use `tensorflow.GraphDef` (e.g., for "freezed graphs") instead of `tensorflow.SavedModel`.

Comment: I am inside the TF repo and using `protoc --decode tensorflow.SavedModel tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto < ~/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb` get only `Failed to parse input.`

Comment: @Amir Does —decode_raw work? That way we can check if it’s a valid .pb file.

Comment: Yes. It does. It decodes the structure (tree-like) of the .pb files, but I'd like to see the values of the weights and other parameters

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to help debugging your problem. It’s strange because your command looks good; that’s how it worked for me. Are you sure you have a [SavedModel and not GraphDef](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/model_files)? Could it be related to TF versions? (I guess not, since you probably have an up-to-date checkout.)

Comment: Actually, this is a frozen .pb file of an old inception-v3 by Google probably in late 2015. Have a look yourself here: https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb

Comment: Yes, you need to use `tensorflow.GraphDef` instead of `tensorflow.SavedModel`; I tried it out and got the desired result.